# Locust load testing report discrepancy in showing the numbers

Tags: load-testing, locust

I have locust set-up to test my azure function app exposed as an HTTP trigger function, I am doing load testing of the function app with 500 users with rate of 50 users per seconds and I am running load test for 2-minutes, The max response time stats the load test taken showing as 18 seconds (18000 ms), however when I am looking at the azure app insights request duration it showing for function app to respond is max of 500ms, If any one can explain why and how locust showing its 18 seconds when realistically its in ms .Please find attached locust report [Locust Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqk5N.jpg)

Below is code snippet for locustfile.py

```
import json
import logging
import json 
import uuid
import random
import os
from random import randint
from locust import task, constant, between
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser


log = logging.getLogger("rest-api-performance-test")


class LocustClient(FastHttpUser):
    

    host = os.environ.get('DEMO_DURABLE_FNAPP_URI') 
    wait_time = between(0.900, 1.000)

    @task
    def load_rest_api_based_service(self):
        try:
            
            api_query_params = ""

            with self.client.post(api_query_params, headers=None, catch_response=False, data=None) as resp_of_api:

                if resp_of_api.status == "200" or resp_of_api.status == "202":
                    log.info("API call resulted in success.")

                else:
                    resp_of_api.failure(resp_of_api.text)
            log.error("API call resulted in failed."  + "Status:" + resp_of_api.status + " | " + resp_of_api.text)

        except Exception as e:
            log.error("Exception occurred! details are {e}")
```

Tried to run the locust test against an api endpoint, the set params were as below, 500 users with rate of 50 users per seconds and ran the load test for 2-minutes. The locust report which is showing the max time taken by API to respond is not matching with actual time api taken to respond.